# Sorting by value with ORDER BY?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

For clarification, are you able to use MySQL this way to sort?

```
ORDER BY CompanyID = XXX DESC
```

What I am trying to do is use one sql query to sort everything where X = Y, in this case, where CompanyID = XXX. All values where CompanyID is not XXX should come after all the results where CompanyID = XXX.

I don't want to limit my query but I do want to sort a particular company above other listings.

Comment: Not very sure of a solution to that, but `... ORDER BY CompanyID = XXX` is definitely wrong. Maybe you could try something like `... WHERE CompanyID LIKE XXX ORDER BY CompanyID DESC`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query is fine. `CompanyID = xxx` yields 1 on a match, and 0 otherwise. Just add the CompanyID column as the secondary order column.

```
ORDER BY CompanyID = XXX DESC, CompanyID ASC
```

This way, you get records where the CompanyID matches your constant first, then the rest are in order.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
ORDER BY CompanyID <> XXX ASC, CompanyID ASC
```

Comment: Of course, why didn't that occur to me. So simple. Will that work with LIKE too? CompanyID LIKE %%, CompanyID = Y ASC

Comment: @Kevin, yes, you can do that with LIKE as well.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me short term. With the added answers here I think I can come up with a more flexible solution in the long run but this got me back on track.

Answer (score 12):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(CompanyID, 'google', 'apple', 'microsoft') ASC
```

Google = first
Microsoft = third
The rest = last

Comment: +1 Interesting, but the field function would return 3 for Microsoft and you're sorting descending, so Microsoft would be first

Comment: But if you sort ascending, the rest will be first!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a case in an order by, like:

```
order by case when CompanyID = XXX then 1 else 2 end
```

Comment: CASE eh? Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably fake it out

```
SELECT CompanyID, IF(CompanyID = XXX, -1, CompanyID) AS sortby
FROM companies
ORDER BY sortby DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using a CASE statement in your order by expression.  When the company id matches your preferred company, return 0, else return 1.  Then order by company name like usual in a secondary order by column.

```
 order by case when CompanyID = XXX then 0 else 1 end, CompanyName
```

That way you have your preferred company at the top, then all of the rest order alphabetically by name (or however you want it ordered).